# How to (quickly) extract t values from lmer model in lme4?

Tags: r, lme4, lmer

I am working with a script that calls `lmer` function of the `lme4` package thousands of times (do not worry,  relevant correction for multiple comparisons is performed later) and would like to save as much time during a single call as possible.

I want to extract t-values from the fitted model, what is the fastest (computation time) way to do this?  I tried using `summary(model)` but it seems to take (much) longer than calling `lmer` itself.  Is it possible to get the t-values from the obtained model without using `summary()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to answer this question is to look at the code of `lme4:::summary.merMod` to figure out how to get the pieces you need.  This ought to do it:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
t.stat <- function(x) fixef(x)/sqrt(diag(vcov(x)))
t.stat(fm1)
##    (Intercept)        Days 
##     36.838311    6.771485 
coef(summary(fm1))[,"t value"]  ## identical
```

Depending on what characteristics are common across your thousands of calls to `lmer` there may be other opportunities for computational efficiency: see e.g. `?refit` and `?modular`.

(Looking at the code of `lme4:::summary.merMod` doesn't reveal anything obviously time-consuming: I would be interested in profiling results that say what's slow in those computations.)

Comment: For some reason I could not replicate my initial problem with using `summary()` - but I have rewritten the code and used a different machine.
Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the response!