# using lmer() efficiently for mass univariate mixed effect analyses

Tags: r, lme4

ideally, i would like to fit an lmer model in the following manner

`model.lmer<-lmer(y ~ a + b + (1|sub))`

where

y: a matrix of N rows and 20k columns 
a: vector of scores with a length of N 
b: vector of scores with a length of N 
sub: subject ID with a length of N

however lmer() does not allow for response variables to be in the form of a matrix, even though it is possible to do `model.lm<-lm(y ~ a + b)`

One possible way to perform this mass univariate mixed effect analysis is to use a for loop to repeat the analyses 20000 times, using a different column of the y matrix in each iteration. But this takes a very long time to complete.

I only need the t-statistics of the predictors to be extracted from the fitted `model.lmer`, I do not require any other statistics to be estimated from the model. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I do not want to model the 'column number of the y matrix' as a predictor in the model, i simply want this to be executed in a mass univariate manner.

Just for some context, i need to run this mass-univariate mixed effect analysis 5000 times with permuted labels to generate a null-distribution of t-statistics, hence the need for efficiency.

Comment: Is it possible to run by parallel computing?

Comment: i was actually planning to parallelized (using `foreach`) the analysis for each of the 5000 iterations, not across each of the columns of the y matrix. 

But before that i'll need to make this analysis (extracting t-stats from mass univariate models) as efficient as possible

Comment: I am not familar with lmer function but I would try to run the source code of lmer function with system.time() or other function that can measure time, then check which part of the function is the most time-consuming and delete the irrelevant code

Comment: do `a` and `b` vary within subject?

Comment: i imagine in a typical scenario, at least one of them will vary within subject

Comment: @doraemon, this is in general a good idea but I don't think it will be feasible with lmer ...

Comment: Yes, I have read the source code of lmer.r and found it that it was too complicated for me to extract the relevant part of code...

Answer (score 2):

(I feel like I must have answered a question like this before, but of course I can't locate it ...)

The `refit()` function will help, although in the example below it only saves about 1/3 of the fitting time.

Helper function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599030/how-to-quickly-extract-t-values-from-lmer-model-in-lme4/23599063#23599063) for getting t-statistics:

```r
t.stat <- function(x) fixef(x)/sqrt(diag(vcov(x)))
```

```r
library(lme4)
ss <- sleepstudy
set.seed(101)
rvec <- sprintf("resp%03d", 1:100)
for (i in rvec) {
   ss[[i]] <- rnorm(nrow(ss))
}
## brute-force refitting
refit1 <- function(nm) { 
   f <- reformulate(c("Days", "(1|Subject)"), response = nm)
   lmer(f, data = ss) |> t.stat()
}
## using refit()

## need baseline fit to modify ...
lmer0 <- lmer(resp001 ~ Days + (1|Subject), ss)
refit2 <- function(nm) {
   refit(lmer0, ss[[nm]]) |> t.stat()
}
```

```r
system.time(sapply(rvec, refit1)))  ## 1.2 seconds
system.time(sapply(rvec, refit2)))  ## 0.8 seconds
```

You may also speed things up if you can use an optimized BLAS, e.g. see [here](https://brettklamer.com/diversions/statistical/faster-blas-in-r/).